# Update Progress Bar Using Percentage Values?

Tags: javascript, click, html5-audio, progress

I created a custom player built to be responsive. So far, everything works fine, except I can't seem to get the audio to play at the spot where the user clicked on the progress bar. All tutorials I've seen for this use pixel values, whereas my player uses percentages, so when I set `barSize = 100 + '%';` it breaks the code and I get an error message saying "Failed to set the `currentTime` property on `HTMLMediaElement`: The provided double value is non-finite".

HTML

```
<!-- PROGRESS BAR -->
<div id="progress_bar">
    <div id="bar"></div>
</div>
```

JS CODE (for progress bar)

```
// PROGRESS BAR

// audio display
var progress = document.getElementById('bar');
//click area
var audioBar = document.getElementById('progress_bar');
var barSize = 100 + '%';

audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', updateProgress, false);


function updateProgress() {
    if (audio.currentTime > 0) {
        var value = 0;
        value = Math.floor((100 / audio.duration) * audio.currentTime);

        progress.style.width = value + '%';
    }       
    else{
        $('#play').html('<img src="img/play.png" width="70" height="70" />');

        $(curTimeDisplay).html('0:00');

        progress.style.width = 0;
    }

}

// CHANGING TIME ON PROGRESS BAR

$('#progress_bar').bind('click', function (e) {
    var $div = $(e.target);
    var $display = $div.find('#progress_bar');

    var offset = $div.offset();
    var x = e.clientX - offset.left;

    //$('#bar').width(x);

    var newtime = x*audio.duration/barSize;

    audio.currentTime = newtime;

    progress.style.width = x + '%';
});
```

CSS

```
#progress_bar {
border:1px solid #500012;
margin:1em 0;
cursor:pointer;
background:#f2f2f2;
width:100%;
height:20px;
display:inline-block;
padding:0;
}

#bar {
background:#77001A;
height:20px;
display:inline-block;
float:left;
width:0%;
}
```

Any help is appreciated :)
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please break this down to the code you believe is related to the question?  This is a lot of code to read through ...

Comment: Hi rfornal. I believe this is what needs to be flushed out: 

var newtime = x*audio.duration/barSize;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clue is in the error message. It wants a double value and your barSize var is calculated as a string when you initialize it. This happens when you add the + '%' to any number - javascript will change that from a numeric to a string value. Doing math operations on a string will give you 'NaN'.

But in this case, you want to advance the media proportionate to where the click occurred, so replace barSize with the pixel width of the total bar area. $('#progress_bar').width() should give you what you need. You will probably want to move the operands of the expression around like so...

Replace

```
var newtime = x*audio.duration/barSize;
```

With

```
var newtime = (x / $('#progress_bar').width()) * audio.duration;
```

Get to know the console and debugging tools in your browser. Adding breakpoints and watches is super helpful with code like this.

Comment: Thanks Ron! I was stuck so much on the percentage that I didn't even think about adding the pixel value as you show above. This definitely did the trick! And good point on the breakpoints and watches. I'll keep it in mind for future projects.

Comment: Hi Ron. I'm sooooo sorry, but I need to bug you for your help again. It seems like the code shows a weird bug where once you click on the progress bar, the bar extends fully (so I'm assuming the 100%) but then after the calculation, ends at the proper clicked area. You can see for yourself here: http://designbyleticia.com/andy/

Could this be solved with a "do first" command?

Once again, thank you!!

Comment: Just change this line 
progress.style.width = x + '%';
to this:
progress.style.width = x + 'px';